# login is not a function error message in Hero ku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

When using Windows and I enter `heroku login` into gitbash, I get the warning message below. How do I solve this?

```
TypeError: cli_ux_1.default.anykey is not a function
at Login.login (C:/Program Files/Heroku/client/node_modules/@heroku-cli/comm             and/lib/login.js:40:44)
```

Comment: If you indent core, error messages and log texts by 4 positions, they are displayed as they should.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling heroku-cli with admin privileges (Run as administrator). Had the same issue, did that and got fixed.